# User name and password

Tags: login

since moving and not being on my computer for a while, I cannot log in.

The version is Ubuntu 12.04 LTS with Linux 3.2.0.25. Not sur eif it is booting?  The last line on the monitor is - TheCollective login:

Seems I may have lost the login and password information... Anyway around this?

Answer (score 2):

To Reset your password, 1)first you will need to reboot and select the option with (Recovery Mode) at the end.

2)Once it boots into the Recovery console, select Root as seen below.

3)Then it will spit you out into the shell. At this point, your Ubuntu installation is Read-only mode. Since we want to make changes, we will need to re-mount the / partition. To do that, type:

`mount -o rw,remount /`

4) At this point, the drive is now set to Read/Write mode.

**Warning** The Root shell is extremely powerful, special care should be taken with any commands run here.

If you have forgotten your username also, you can run the following, passive, command and refresh your memory:

`ls /home`

5) Now that the username has been recovered, we are ready to reset the password:

`passwd username`

And replace username with the one you want to reset the password to. Then it will prompt you for the new password.

6) The last step is to type `exit` and select "resume" from the resulting menu. Once you are back in to the GUI, you should be able to log in with your new password.

Special note: I had pictures and everything for you, but the AskUbuntu refuses to allow picture posting until I have at least 10 reputation. But you can find the same guide, with pictures, [here](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/resetpassword)

Answer (score 0):

If no separate root account or other users allowed to sudo, the best may be to start your computer from LiveCD - assuming of course here that it's just your desktop an you can reboot it at any time.

Once Live system started, you can mount your disk under some mountpoint and edit original /etc/shadow to remove password string.
Restart computer to your proper system - log in without password then and set a new one.